# Magento 2.1.11 add to cart not working

Tags: addtocart, magento2.1.11

I've upgraded my M2 CE from 2.1.3 to 2.1.11. Everything seems to be working, but I can't add product to cart. From any location on the website. There's nothing is reports nor log files.

When I click ADD TO CART, it's adding it forever. I get a blank popup where it should say that my product is added to shopping cart, and loader over the shopping cart icon is just hanging in an endless loop.

I've tried several different solutions I've found from people having the same issue, but nothing seem to work.

Please help, this is a huge showstopper for me.

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors in browser console?

Comment: Can you re-deploy the site again and check with clear your browser cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem by change from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

Please try this: `Dashboard->Stores->Configuration->General->Web`. At `Base URLs` tab, change the value in `Base URL field` from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. And do the same with `Base URLs (Secure)` tab

Comment: Hi Nam

This was already in the database. Issues required way too deep digging, and time, which wasn't planned at all. So the upgrade is revoked, for the time being.

Thanks.


Regards,
Nemanja.